# I can not repository.save(mydata) I am looking for a pretty alternative to JOIN with Spring + Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I am beginning to touch Cassandra, but I am in trouble because I can not do JOIN.
Since JOIN can not be done with CQL as it is, I thought about looking for alternative means and joining it on the Java application side.

Specifically, I used @OneToMany and I tried joining Entities, but the following error appears.

Is there any good solution?

■Project structure

SpringBoot + Spring Data for Apache Cassandra

Version:

- Spring Boot :: (v1.3.5.RELEASE)
- spring-data-cassandra-1.3.5.RELEASE
- cassandra 2.1.16

■Error log

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown identifier emp
at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:102) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:149) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:183) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2300(RequestHandler.java:44) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:751) ~[cassandra-driver-core-2.1.9.jar:na]
```

■ Source: Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/DepartmentsCassandra/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public ModelAndView form(
        @RequestParam("department_id") int department_id,
        @RequestParam("department_name") String department_name,
        ModelAndView mav){
    Departments mydata = new Departments();
    mydata.setDepartment_id(department_id);
    mydata.setDepartment_name(department_name);
    repository.save(mydata);// ← Error occurred !!!
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/DepartmentsCassandra");
}
```

■ Source: Entity: Departments

```
package com.example.cassandra.entity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import org.springframework.cassandra.core.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;
@Table(value="departments")
public class Departments {

@PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "department_id",ordinal = 1,type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
private int department_id;

@Column(value = "department_name")
private String department_name;

public Departments(int department_id,String department_name){
    this.department_id = department_id;
    this.department_name = department_name;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="department_id",insertable=false,updatable=false)
private List<Employees> emp = new ArrayList<Employees>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, "client side join" is a general anti-pattern using Cassandra, since you do two queries instead of one every time and hence lose the performance gain.
The way to go is creating a broad table for each query - including all "joined" data.
So in your case, create a table employee_by_department or something alike.
Check out the introductory courses on datastax.com - they are great :-)

Comment: To rob, thank you for valuable advice immediately. I will create employee_by_department.
However, it is good now because it is in the study stage, but when you want to replace the existing RDBMS system with Cassandra, it is very painful to fix all the joining points.

Is there any good idea?

Comment: It will be painful. Afaik, there is no "easy way" for a migration to C*. You will also have to deal with new challenges like keeping the tables in sync (from C* 3.0 look up materialized views) and "missing" transactions you probably rely upon as well.

Comment: To rob, Thank you very much for valuable information. There seems to be many things to think about variously. .